# Getting an array of a parameter from repeated nested column in BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, data-structures, google-bigquery

I have a table where one column is defined as:

```
my_column ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value FLOAT64, description STRING>>
```

Is there some easy way how to get an array of `value` parameters for each row using `SELECT` statement?

Obviously, this does not work:

```
SELECT my_column.value
FROM my_table
```

I could do it using `UNNEST` and then `ARRAY_AGG` grouping through all other columns but it just feels like a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> I could do it using UNNEST and then ARRAY_AGG grouping through all other columns but it just feels like a hack.

No, this is not a hack at all. Meantime you can avoid using explicit UNNEST here

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT value FROM t.my_column) AS my_column_values
FROM `project.dataset.my_table` t
```

or

```
#standardSQL
SELECT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(value) FROM t.my_column) my_column_values
FROM `project.dataset.my_table` t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unnest and reaggregate:

```
SELECT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(c.value)
        FROM UNNEST(my_column) c
       ) as c_values
FROM my_table
```